# Amazon AWS EC2 Web Server Forbids Accessing Image Files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm running a website using an Amazon Web Services EC2 instance, but I'm having trouble accessing certain images stored in my website's directory.  The website can be viewed here: http://jkmrcsolutions.com

The strange thing is, some images can be accessed just fine, and others give a 403 Access Forbidden error.  The problem is well illustrated in the images subdirectory: http://jkmrcsolutions.com/images/
Some of the images, like the JKM RC Solutions banner, are easily viewable, while others give the aforementioned 403 error.

I've restarted the EC2 instance and double-checked that the HTTP security group is enabled, but it hasn't solved the problem.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!
-John

Comment: Windows instance or amazon linux??

Comment: Amazon Linux 64 bit.

Comment: Thanks sailesh!  I'm a noob at Linux and terminal, would you mind explaining what the command you suggested does?  I assume that `find /var/www/html/images` navigates to the directory of html/images (where the problem is occurring), but I am not familiar with the rest of the commands (although I know that chmod has to do with changing permissions).  Sorry to be a bother!  I'm still learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the permissions of all the files like,

```
find /var/www/html/images -type f -exec chmod a+r {} \;
```

a+r is setting read permissions to all.
You need to be root user to execute this

Comment: Thanks sailesh!  I'm a noob at Linux and terminal, would you mind explaining what the command you suggested does?  I assume that `find /var/www/html/images` navigates to the directory of html/images (where the problem is occurring), but I am not familiar with the rest of the commands (although I know that chmod has to do with changing permissions).  Sorry to be a bother!  I'm still learning :)

Comment: type -f is to find all the files, `{}` is replaced by the file path, `/;` is the end of the command and here `;` is escaped, otherwise it would be interpreted by the shell instead of find.

Comment: Ok, so if I nagivate to the html directory manually using cd, I could type `chmod a+r` and things would work out?

Comment: Thanks for the super fast responses!  I went to the html folder and ran `chmod a+r`, and it said that it was missing an operand after a+r.

Comment: `chmod a+r images/amazon_logo.png` in this way.

Comment: Amazon logo seems to be visible now. If you do this way, you need to change the permissions individually for all the images. Hence you can do this way to change all the images permissions.
 `find images -type f -exec chmod a+r {} \;`

Comment: Great!  That worked, thanks a bunch!  I ended up running a recursive chmod on the images folder with the command `chmod a+r images -R` ...everything works perfectly now.  I appreciate your help!